# how to write a custom django relational database backend

Tags: django

My django app needs to support data coming from a datasource backed by [Composite Software](http://www.compositesw.com).  Composite exposes its data over jdbc/odbc, but it uses non-standard sql syntax.  I've tried using django-pyodbc as the backend engine, but it errors out immediately on connection initialization as it's sending hardcoded initialization commands in syntax that Composite doesn't support (like `SET ...`).

The easiest way to get this to work, obviously, is to simply code directly against pyodbc.  But before I go down that route, I'd like to explore the possibility of writing a custom backend.  I've seen a couple of django-backend templates written for non-relational backends.  I haven't been able to find a similar template for relational databases, though.  Does such a thing exist?  Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the SQLite relational backend is quite simple if you're looking to go that road, maybe have a look https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py